# Can't find pointerpressed row in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I am following a tutorial to build a game in that it says

> Go to the XAML designer and use the Document Outline window to select human
>   (remember, it’s the StackPanel that contains a Circle and a Rectangle). Then go to the
>   Properties window and press the
>   button to switch it to show event handlers. Find
>   the **PointerPressed** row and double-click in the empty box.
>   [image]

but i can't able to find the PointerPressed row and i am using visual studio 2015 but the tutorial follows visual studio 2012.

[image: this is what I am getting]

the above options are what I am getting.

Comment: The VS version should not be the problem, could you show a screenshot/snippet of what you're seeing in Properties? Assuming you selected the stackpanel correctly.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL i just now added the snippet of mine

Comment: As a side thought, could you recheck step 1, your project type (and make sure it matches the one in your tutorial, e.g. Windows 8 App or whichever it says).

Answer (score 0):

yeah, its been 3 years but its never late! Theres still some people who dont know what they should to do. Use MouseLeftButtonUp